# Android studio cordovaRun cannot run using device

Tags: android, cordova, xiaomi

I'm developing a simple app using Android Studio with Cordova. But when I run I've got this error:

```
(node:9856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to execute shell command "input,keyevent,82"" on device: Error: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe: Command failed with exit code 4294967177
    at D:\sandbox\platforms\android\cordova\lib\Adb.js:88:25
    at _rejected (D:\sandbox\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:864:24)
    at D:\sandbox\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:890:30
    at Promise.when (D:\sandbox\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\sandbox\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:808:41)
    at D:\sandbox\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (D:\sandbox\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (D:\sandbox\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:9856) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9856) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My device is Redmi 4A and I already enable the USB Debugging and Install via USB.

Answer (score 6):

Enable:

1. USB debugging
2. Install via USB
3. **USB debugging (Security settings)** *<--  this is important*

Comment: USB debugging (Security settings) was the only problem!
Thanks man @Aldracor